# Fixing garbled id3v2 tags with incorrect encoding using mid3v2

Tags: command-line, music, id3

I have been using `id3v2` to automatically tag music files (title, album, artist).
While id3v2 displays the metadata correctly, other players do not - here I have an example of issues with À/è/û and this occurs for seemingly anything other than characters found in English (or 7 bit ASCII?).

I found that using `mid3v2` instead fixes this, but I still have hundreds of songs with tagging like this.

For example:

```
id3v2 -l files/Pomme\ -\ On\ brûlera.mp3
```

gives

```
id3v1 tag info for files/Pomme - On brûlera.mp3:
Title  : On brûlera                     Artist: Pomme                         
Album  : À peu près                    Year:     , Genre: Unknown (255)
Comment:                                 Track: 0
id3v2 tag info for files/Pomme - On brûlera.mp3:
TPE1 (Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)): Pomme
TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): À peu près
TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): On brûlera
```

However, most music players, e.g. MPV, Musicolet & Sayonara, display this incorrectly:

```
mid3v2 -l files/Pomme\ -\ On\ brûlera.mp3
```

gives

```
IDv2 tag info for files/Pomme - On brûlera.mp3
TALB=Ã peu prÃ¨s
TIT2=On brÃ»lera
TPE1=Pomme
```

An example of how it should be:

```
mid3v2 -l files/Pomme\ -\ À\ peu\ près.mp3
```

gives

```
IDv2 tag info for files/Pomme - À peu près.mp3
TALB=À peu près
TIT2=À peu près
TPE1=Pomme
TSSE=Lavf60.3.100
```

But changing the TSSE of other songs does nothing seemingly, and the other tags remain garbled.
e.g.

```
IDv2 tag info for files/Pomme - On brûlera.mp3
TALB=Ã peu prÃ¨s
TIT2=On brÃ»lera
TPE1=Pomme
TSSE=Lavf60.3.100
```

Is there some way of automatically un-garbling all of the metadata? This would be a mighty task to do by hand.
Current solution would be to parse the titles to the new artist/title and then do the albums in batch where possible.